# creating lookups between two databases in vb.net

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Here is quick overview. I have an employee database with ID, name, phone num, division, location etc. It will all get stored in a table in a database called EMP. Now i have another Database that is central to other apps that may use it for a look up that contains all the divisions and locations. I want to use a lookup for division and location and this resides in another database on the same server that stores the information. When i use a datagrid and bound controls for my employee table. I can change the columns to drop downs but i want to point it to another db and lookup table, with still creating the foreign relationship so when i update the lookup (source) it will update the other applications db. whats the easiest way to do lookups to other database tables to pull back information and set it. any ideas.

Comment: Do it in SQL on the server, as either a view or stored procedure, and query that from your VB.

Comment: problem is , i have an employee database that stores the look up values to these divisions and locations.  So if you change the souce database and delete a division, then the view doesn't contain that anymore thus causing an issue...views can't contain FK realtionship

Comment: View are basically stored queries, that don't hold the data. You will see updates real-time.

Comment: yes, i know that.. you don't understand what i'm asking.
I have an emp DB. stores IDs, names, location and division.  Location and Division are look up tables, BUT stored in another database.  Sure fine i can run a query that populates the drop downs and then stores the ids in the employee database.   But what if i go to the source database that stores the ids for div and location and delete or update. Ya it will show up in the list but it won't update data that was saved in the employee database to begin with

Comment: To do the UPDATE in the other table, if I understand correctly, you could use a trigger on the table that will run an update against the other database. BIG question is, what is the DBMS?

Comment: Trigger, as I mentioned before. Either that or do the saves through a Stored Procedure which can be coded to enforce this business rule. I prefer trigger because you cannot force other developers to use the stored procedure consistently.

Comment: Are you saying you have foreign keys _accross_ databases? design smell!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are following NORMAL FORM, the only thing on the employee database that references the Location and Division tables is an ID, which would never change, only be deleted.  Therefore you can create DELETE triggers on these tables that will do whatever you think it should do to the employee table when a Location or Division is deleted.

Just make sure you have the security setup so whoever can delete from the Division/Location tables can also perform the coded action on the employee table.